# Get link value in html document with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a link in a table like:

```
    <td class="ms-vb" width="100%">
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/Lists/Business%20Divisions/DispForm.aspx?ID=2" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Train<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" alt="" width="1" border="0" height="1">
</a></td>
```

How can I get the value Train with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I currently get the querystring value from every link and push them into an array with the following code:

```
$("table").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).addClass("table" + index);
});


var hrefs = new Array();
$('.table449').children().children().each(function(){
var link = ($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
var startIndex = link.indexOf(",'");
var endIndex = link.indexOf("');");
if ( startIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0 ) {
    var linkID = link.substring( startIndex+2, endIndex );
  hrefs.push(linkID);
}
alert(hrefs);
});
```

What I want to do is to store the values like Train in another array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to tell with such a small snippet.  In the provided snippet either of these would work:

```
$("td a").text();

$(".ms-vb a").text();
```